# passing forth and back variables between c++ DLL and C# class

Tags: c#, c++, dll, marshalling

Please See [this page for more details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)

I have implemented the c++ DLL example as explained in MSDN. The example allows to design a DLL which exposes the 4 basic arithmetic operations between 2 double values. and also explain how to consume this dll in c++ console app.

My question, is it possible to consume this DLL in a C# Console Application ? if so, how can I do that ? I mean to send 2 values from the C# Console Application to c++ DLL and get back their arithmetic result.

Learning such thing is very interesting to programmers who wish to use both c# and c++ I guess, I am one of those guys therefore for me and future people please **provide a demo based on MSDN example if possible**

Comment: There are demos and tutorials out there. You need to do your own research. Please code up your own example, as it's the best way to learn, and come back with any *specific* question you have about *code you've already written.*

Comment: So this website about questions and get answers ? or about asking questions and waiting for people like you to tell that there are demos on the web ? this website used to be great but with downvoting and rude users i think it gets very bad reputation by time

Comment: If you are using classes like the example you can read this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx) , but if it is only for static methods, you might want to 'publish' them as static non-class functions and use `__declspec(dllexport)` [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dt232c9t.aspx) in combination with the `DllImport` attribute [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(v=vs.90).aspx). The rest you will have to figure out on your own, or return with a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you @FrederickGrumieaux

Comment: @FrederickGrumieaux How to add the c++ Dll to the C# Console App ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/e59b22c5(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx). All that's needed to call MessageBox in User32.dll is this (from the example there):

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)] 
public static extern int MessageBox(IntPtr h, string m, string c, int type);
```

And then you can call it like a regular C# method. If you have more complex types, like classes, then read [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/eaw10et3(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx).

Comment: How to add the c++ Dll to the C# Console App ? @wezten

Comment: Place it in the application folder, or in one of the [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) folders.